# How to control field access with cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, acl9

I have a `Book` model which has a `cover` field which is the path to an image that is uploaded.

But I want to restrict the uploading of the cover if a user is not a particular user level.

How do I do this with CanCan or should I use acl9 for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CanCan can do this for you – check out this link: [CanCan wiki: Custom Actions](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Custom-Actions)

Alternatively try checking out the `attr_accessible` [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible) with the new `:as` option. if this would work better for you?

Comment: that's cool i thought i'd be forced to use REST actions only, I was having a nightmare thinking i would have to create models just for certain actions.